# Removing side effect from observable implementation

Tags: rxjs

I have the following observable implementation

```js
  public getFromAddressSubjectObservable() {
    let _address: string;
    return this.fromAddressSubject.pipe(
      tap((address: string) => _address = address),
      mergeMap(() => this.rpc.call('', 'smsglocalkeys', [])),
      map((keys: SmsgLocalKeysResult) => [...keys.smsg_keys, ...keys.wallet_keys]),
      filter((keys: Array<SmsgLocalKey>) => !keys.some(k => k.address === _address)),
      mergeMap(() => this.rpc.call('', 'smsggetpubkey', [_address])),
      mergeMap((pubkeyData: PublicKeyData) => this.rpc.call('', 'smsgaddaddress', [ pubkeyData.address, pubkeyData.publickey ])),
      mergeMap(() => this.rpc.call('', 'smsgaddlocaladdress', [_address]))
    )
  }
```

I would like to know if there's a way that I could have this function without side effects, i.e. passing the value of `_address` from the first operator to the last one of the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be the following. You start defining a method, `closureAddressMethod`, which expects address as parameter, like this

```
public closureAddressMethod(address: string) {
    return this.rpc.call('', 'smsglocalkeys', [])).pipe(
      map((keys: SmsgLocalKeysResult) => [...keys.smsg_keys, ...keys.wallet_keys]),
      filter((keys: Array<SmsgLocalKey>) => !keys.some(k => k.address === _address)),
      mergeMap(() => this.rpc.call('', 'smsggetpubkey', [_address])),
      mergeMap((pubkeyData: PublicKeyData) => this.rpc.call('', 'smsgaddaddress', [ pubkeyData.address, pubkeyData.publickey ])),
      mergeMap(() => this.rpc.call('', 'smsgaddlocaladdress', [_address]))
    )
  }
```

and then you use this method within the pipe of `getFromAddressSubjectObservable` method, like this

```
public getFromAddressSubjectObservable() {
    return this.fromAddressSubject.pipe(
      mergeMap(address => closureAddressMethod(address))
    )
  }
```

Last point, unrelated to your question, is about using `mergeMap` in a situation which I see as a chain of sequential calls to some remote server. Maybe, in such cases, you may want to consider using `concatMap`, as suggested in [this video](https://youtu.be/Dsku0F4lU3A?list=PLJBWPTwg7fuNKFg5BRXKTvDrEi-45YzSE&t=79) from Ben Lesh.